# Width transitioning from fixed size to "auto" using CSS without Javascript

Tags: css, width, css-transitions

I'm having a bit of a problem making script-less CSS-only animated transition of an element that's initially set to a fixed width and should expand on mouse over to auto width according to content in it. When mouse goes out it should collapse back to fixed width.

Let's say I have a menu:

```
<menu>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item with long text</li>
</menu>
```

Initially it would display as a collapsed 50px wide vertical bar with icons only. When one mouses over it reveals icon labels.

[This is a simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/E34Hm/) of what I'm trying to achieve. First menu is the one that needs to transition and second one is there just to show what auto width should be for this amount of content.

### Problem

This is just part of the whole CSS that plays an important role here:

```
menu {
    width: 50px;
}

menu:hover {
    width: auto; /* setting to other fixed width works as expected */
}
```

The problem is that when you set `width` to `auto` one of the two will happen:

- Browser animates from fixed width 0 (Chrome) - if we then add `min-width` it does next one
- Browser doesn't animate anything just applies new style

Comment: Have you thought about having the text slide in from the left side of the screen instead of just from the side of the li icon? It might make it easier because you can just go from `left: -30em` for example to `left: 50px` (the width of your icons + padding) or whatever it ends up being as the width of the icon column.

Comment: @IlanBiala: Can you create a JSFiddle because I'm not completely sure how you envisioned this...

Comment: This is close to what I was thinking of, but for some reason the `.hover()` method in jQuery isn't working like it usually does for me, but anyway here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/E34Hm/17/ Using pebbl's answer below you can probably get it working and use just CSS, but I just wanted to show you another way. If you can't get it to work just by mousing over the icons, trying just clicking, for some reason that is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle I linked above?

Comment: @IlanBiala: I did yes, but that's not really accessible nor HTML valid. And you've actually separated icons from text. That's not an option. Suppose some text wraps into two lines (I know I've set it not to,  but it may) and icons wouldn't line up any more. You've also removed shadow on labels `div`. If I add it we can see double shadow while element's being trasitioned... Even though it could solve the problem for some, it won't for me. BTW: toolbar isn't touching left window border. I understand why you did that. There're too many shortcomings in your solution and is also too hackish.

Comment: Yea, it isn't too semantic and it definitely won't work for lines that wrap, so I wouldn't go with it, just proposing it just in case it could've worked, just trying to help. I don't want to bloat this question, so why don't you join the room I made called CSS Transitions and maybe we can work something out together that will work.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the `max-width` trick, it's not perfect, but it gets around the problems with transitioning a numeric value to a string state:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cqmuf/1/

*(the above has been updated with `float:left`)*

The downside to this method is that you have to set a max width for your menu, but then I usually find that this is a good thing to do anyway.

**markup:**

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">[i] Hello</a>
  <a href="#">[i] There</a>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
div a {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu {
  transition: all 2s;
  max-width: 17px;
  /*
   here you can set float:left or position:absolute
   which will force the menu to collapse to it's minimum
   width which, when expanded, will be the actual menu
   item widths and not max-width.
  */
  float: left;
}

.menu:hover {
  /*
   If you have the possibility of varied widths, i.e. multilingual
   then make sure you use a max-width that works for them all. Either
   that or do what a number of multilingual sites do and set a body
   class that states the current language, from there you can then
   tailor your max-width differently e.g. wider for German.
  */
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

Example of seperate dimensions for multilingual:

```
.lang-de .menu:hover { max-width: 400px; }
.lang-gb .menu:hover { max-width: 300px; }
```

So instead of transitioning the width, you are actually modifying the `max-width` property, which you can set a fixed value to more easily, all because it will only come into use when this limit has been reached, and remains invisible until then.

Comment: How would you suggest to set `max-width` value? If I set it in design time, then it's the same as if I wouldn't be using `auto` for width. But if I set it during runtime using Javascript, then I may as well manipulate that particular style definition and set width accordingly. So how does this solve my problem then? One more thing to consider. Suppose I have a multi-lang site so my labels have differet widths in different languages. Hence `auto`.

Comment: Max-width would be useful in percentage/relative if you are doing a responsive site because in any case you don't want the navbar taking up the whole screen just because a language uses more characters..but still your thought is correct, it would be best to transition to auto.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - the benefit of `max-width` is that you don't need to know the actual width. As long as you set it to an amount larger than what you will need (something sensible) you shouldn't have a problem and you can transition quite happily. Depending on how you set up your menu items they should only ever expand to their actual width and not the max width i.e. use `float:left` or `position:absolute` to collapse the container.

Comment: To whomever downvoted, please give a reason as to why. This is a workable solution to a problem that doesn't yet have a 100% perfect pure css answer. The day we can transition between a `number` and `auto` will be a happy one, *if* it ever occurs.

Comment: @pebbl: I downvoted, because I don't see any particular benefit with your solution as already mentioned in the first comment. And I did so because your answer gained two votes, leading other potential developer to believe that this has already been sufficiently answered.

Comment: @pebbl: But to continue why I think this is not a solution:  **First**: if you use `max-width` your transitions will be timed for the full value of `width` so timing will be off. By using % for `width` and fixed units for `max width` makes this uncontrollable. **Second**: if I set `max-width` in design-time to some sensible fixed value I could easily do the same with `width` itself. This solution isn't any better than having set a fixed value to `width` for both states. Actually it's a bit worse as it breaks transition timings.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik As I said this isn't perfect, it is however the best you're going to get with css for now, & it definitely isn't wrong. Timing transitions are off slightly (can be improved depending on easing & speed), but you do not state this as a prerequisite. It *is* better than setting width because you do not need to know exact values, just a rough maximum, this stopgap has been used by many. You can also obvsiously define `max-width` as a percentage. However, by the sounds of *your requirements*, you should use JavaScript for now & then wait for improved support of `calc()` or `attr()`.

Comment: @pebbl: define *rough maximum*. How do you suggest to provide that? As a design-time constant? In whatever unit? Likely some fixed one, not % as texts don't scale with screen size. And also: timing can be off by a lot. If you'd set `width` to 100% and `max-width`, timing would be off by 1/2 with improper easing anyway. Because easing animation is calculated on `width` that get's later limited by `max-width` setting. The greater the difference the greater timing error. So it's not something *slightly*.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Obviously if you set ridiculous values, you will get ridiculous results, as is the case with anything. You seem to be forgetting that this is a work-around that has been proffered as a *possible* solution in order to help. Myself and others have been able to make this work, with only slight time delays, I am sorry that you are unable to -- perhaps you need to rethink your menu design. Good luck with finding another solution.