# Why is my transition not working on <hr>?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this `<div>` and a `<hr>` in an `<a>`. When someone hovers the whole thing it should make a fluid animation.

```css
.wrap:hover div{
  transition: all 2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.wrap:hover hr{
  transition: all 2s linear;
  width: 200px;
}

.image{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

hr{
  min-width: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrap">
  <div class="image">
     Content
  </div>
  <hr class="hr-animation">
</a>
```

The transition works at `<div>`. But why is my `<hr>` not fluid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Width transitioning from fixed size to "auto" using CSS without Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549282/width-transitioning-from-fixed-size-to-auto-using-css-without-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a width to start with and put the transition for the hr, not the hover.

```css
.wrap:hover div {
  transition: all 2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.wrap:hover hr {
  width: 200px;
}

.image {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

hr {
  min-width: 20px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrap">
  <div class="image">
    Content
  </div>
  <hr class="hr-animation">
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the same parameter in the original rule for `hr` as in the `hover` rule, which is `width`, not `min-width`:

```css
.wrap:hover div{
  transition: all 2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.wrap:hover hr{
  transition: all 2s linear;
  width: 200px;
}

.image{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

hr{
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrap">
  <div class="image">
     Content
  </div>
  <hr class="hr-animation">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you set the `min-width` of the hr but not the `width` in it's not hovered state. You're trying to transition from something not set to `width: 200px;". 
Define the width to fix it.

```css
.wrap:hover div{
  transition: all 2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.wrap:hover hr{
  width: 200px;
}

.image{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

hr{
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrap">
  <div class="image">
     Content
  </div>
  <hr class="hr-animation">
</a>
```

Comment: When you have the transition for the :hover, it jumps right back into place when the mouse goes away

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
hr {
  min-width: 20px;<<--------
  //more code----
}
```

**To:**

```
hr {
  width: 20px;<<--------
  //more code----
}
```

```css
  .wrap:hover div{
  transition: all 2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.wrap:hover hr{
  transition: all 2s linear;
  width: 200px;
}

.image{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

hr {
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a class="wrap">
  <div class="image">
     Content
  </div>
  <hr class="hr-animation">
</a>
```