# Smoothly scale an img and automatically scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, toggle

I am trying to set up a basic functionality to smoothly toggle an img on click from being longer than screen to being on a display (fit to window size) (back and forth). It kinda works already using percentages etc.

My issue is I'd like to have a smooth animated transition between the 2 states but the img is being brutally scaled.
Also whenever I try to work with "transition" or "animation", when the img come back to its original size, it will block the scrolling. Same issue happened after I tried to use keyframes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        img {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            padding: 2%;
            width: 90vw;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .scaled {
            width: auto;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten1.png"> 
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten2.png">
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten3.png">
</body>
<script>
    $(".item").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('scaled');
        $(this).scrollIntoView();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Also I'd like to have the window view (by that I mean the location of the scrolling on the page) centered on the img whenever it is scaled. I am currently trying to use scrollIntoView for that purpose but nothing seems to happen.

Thank you in advance. First time posting here. I don't feel like this should be too difficult but will probably be on a different level than what I can figure out for now ଘ(੭*ˊᵕˋ)੭* ̀ˋ

---

Also tried the following, but the img stay stuck at 90vw and 100vh ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        img {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            padding: 2%;
            width: 90vw;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            object-fit: contain;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <img class="item" src="images/kitten1.png">
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten2.png">
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten3.png">

</body>
<script>
    $(".item").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('scaled')) {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "none",
            width: "90vw"
        }, 1000);
        $(this).removeClass('scaled');
    }
        else {
            $(this).animate({
            width: "none",
            height: "100vh"
        }, 1000);
        $(this).addClass('scaled');
        }
    });

</script></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll to clicked item, use `$(this)[0].scrollIntoView();` because `.scrollIntoView()` is JavaScript function, not jQuery.

#### Smooth scale (transition).

CSS does not support from auto width to specific width or the same to height transition. Reference: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549282/width-transitioning-from-fixed-size-to-auto-using-css-without-javascript), [2](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/)

##### Option 1. Use one side instead.

You can use `max-height` or `max-width` only. The good thing is you write less JavaScript and CSS responsive (media query) also supported without any addition. Bad thing is it just only support one side (width or height).

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        img {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            padding: 2%;
            max-width: 100vw;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            transition: all .3s;
        }

        .scaled {
            max-width: 50vw;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten1.png"> 
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten2.png">
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten3.png">
</body>
<script>
    $(".item").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('scaled');
        $(this)[0].scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth"
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/yop14u8b/1/)

##### Option 2. Use JavaScript.

The code below will be use a lot of JavaScript to make CSS transition work properly from width to height. Good thing: of cause support transition between width and height. Bad thing: CSS media query for responsive image will not work properly. Need more JS for that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
        img {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        padding: 2%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all .3s;
        height: auto;
        width: 90vw;
    }

    .scaled {
        height: 100vh;
        width: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten1.png"> 
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten2.png">
    <img class="item" src="images/kitten3.png">
</body>
<script>
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    // wait until all images loaded.
    // loop each <img> that has class `item` and set height.
    $('img.item').each((index, item) => {
      $(item).attr('data-original-height', $(item)[0].offsetHeight);
      $(item).css({
        'height': $(item)[0].offsetHeight
      });
    });
  });


  $(".item").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('scaled')) {
      // if already has class `scaled`
      // going to remove that class after this.
      if ($(this).attr('data-scaled-width') === undefined) {
        // get and set original width to data attribute.
        $(this).attr('data-scaled-width', $(this)[0].offsetWidth);
      }
      $(this).css({
        'height': $(this).data('originalHeight'),
        'width': ''
      });
      $(this).removeAttr('data-original-height');

      $(this).removeClass('scaled');
    } else {
      // if going to add `scaled` class.
      if ($(this).attr('data-original-height') === undefined) {
        // get and set original height to data attribute.
        $(this).attr('data-original-height', $(this)[0].offsetHeight);
      }
      $(this).css({
        'height': '',
        'width': $(this).data('scaledWidth')
      });
      $(this).removeAttr('data-scaled-width');

      $(this).addClass('scaled');
      // check again to make sure that width has been set.
      if ($(this)[0].style.width === '') {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log($(this)[0].style.width);
          $(this).css({
            'width': $(this)[0].offsetWidth
          });
          console.log('css width for image was set after added class.');
        }, 500);// set timeout more than transition duration in CSS.
      }
    }

    $(this)[0].scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/2hk7oL1p/)

Comment: Seems perfect on fiddle thank you. Still I don't know why but when I try to use it on my Brackets the scrolling gets stuck after clicking. Do you think it is due to Bracket and I should use another software?

Comment: Make sure that `scrollIntoView()` is use with `$(this)[0]` (must have `[0]` to be nomal JS selector).

Comment: Had to change for vscode which is not a bad thing, no problem finally. But there is an issue : I wanted the image to change from a max-width to a max-height, which doesn't work with this solution (noticed it late as I thought I was done with the issue). Do you have any idea or trick for that?

Comment: I tried that but not possible. Sorry.

Comment: @AlexandreD. I was updated the code to use more JS, please try again. It should now work on transition cross between width <-> height.

Comment: The bad news is it does not support CSS responsive image, you have to create JS for that again. This cost more & more time & your brain while use one side such as `max-height` will be easier.

Comment: I will try it today, thank you so much for the in-depth reply!

Comment: It seems that the images are weirdly reacting to window size modification. I will use the first one then, but thank you for the JS solution!